# Sort by (available yes, price low to high), (available no, price low to high)

Tags: wordpress

I currently have products which are available and not available indicated by Y and N, they also have a price. Currently there are sorted by availability using:

```
'post_type'=>'products',
'orderby'=>'meta_value',
'meta_key'=>'available',
'order'=>'ASC',
```

What I would like is to display them like:

Available Y, price low to high

Available N, price low to high

Price field is called price. I am a bit confused by the codex page.

I have tried this:

```
'post_type'=>'products',
'meta_query' => array(
    'active' => array(
        'key' => 'available',
    ),
    'cost' => array(
        'key' => 'price',
    ),
),
'orderby' => array(
    'active' => 'ASC',
    'cost' => 'ASC',
),
```

This successfully sorts by available, but they are not sorted by price low to high within availability.

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please provide which code you have tried?

Comment: Of course, main post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to specify that price was 'NUMERIC' and then this worked.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'available' => array(
        'key' => 'available',
    ),
    'price' => array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
),
'orderby' => array(
    'available' => 'ASC',
    'price' => 'ASC',
),
```